# passing combobox selectedItem of one to another form Constructor returns null .why?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to call a comboboxselectedItem of one form to another form constructor. So that I can assign it some variable and use it for other purposes.

Form that contains comboboxvalue is Mode Form:

```
    public Mode()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Mode_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        comboBox1.Focus();
        String query = "select [test_no],[test_name] from [Test]";
        ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(query);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "test_name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "test_no";
        comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["tablename"];
        panel3.Controls.Add(comboBox1);
        panel3.Controls.Add(Runbutton);                 
    }

      private void Runbutton_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         label3.Enabled = true;
         val = Convert.ToString(comboBox1.Text);
         Test test = new Test(val);
         Test test1 = new Test();
         test1.Activate();
         test1.Focus();
         this.Hide();
         test1.ShowDialog();  
     }

      private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          val = Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedItem);

      }
```

Test Form:code

```
 string parentform;

    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RunFirst_Settings();
        UserLogin login = new UserLogin();
        login.Hide();
        login.Visible = false;
    }

     public Test(string Mode)
     {
         parentform = Mode;
     }

    private void Startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        stopwatch.Start();
        timer1.Start();
        ts=new ThreadStart(ProcessStarted);
        th=new Thread(ts);                 
        th.Start();

    }

     private void ProcessStarted()
    {
        if (parentform != null)
        {
            // Here every time it returns a null value. Before it was 
            // showing the exact selectedItem of combobox in Mode form:
            MMTest(parentform);

        }


        else
        {
             //other code to be done

        }
  }
```

Now how can I get the exact selectedItem of combobox? any suggestion?
If I call Test(string Mode) constructor only in Runbutton_Click_2() in Mode form it show blank form, not the actual test form.

Where is my mistake? How can I rectify it to get required result.

Comment: First of all - combobox.Text is already is string - you do not need to cast it; if you checking parentform != null, then it can not be null, and nullref is hiding inside your MMTest...

Comment: Thanks.I was just trying different ways as combobox.selectedItem,selectedValue and all.So i didnt remove the casting part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the click event handler, you are calling parameterized constructor on different object and displaying the form from another object (test and test1). So, the test1 instance never really received the selected item text.

Edit:

1. Replace `Test test1 = new Test();` by `Test test1 = new Test(val);`.
2. In the parameterized constructor, add `:this()` to call default constructor as well.

Comment: Thanks.I understood what every u said but how i can solve this? suppose if i cal the parameterzied constructor object it shows a blank form not the required form.

Comment: Probably he should get rid of his first constructor Test(), as he would never be used, and move initialization part to parameterized one...

Comment: @JleruOHeP If OP is never  going to use it, just make it private. As in newer .Net version, default ctor is added by default.

Comment: I know, but I think that it would better to have only one of them, just in case... If there will be need of additional constructor - he can add it later!

Comment: Thanks alot danish and JleruOHeP for the idea ans solution..I was struggling from yesterday to get the result

Answer (score 0):

As far as you will use only parameterized constructor (because you need that parameter) remove your first constructor `Test()` or make it private, to make sure that you will not call it occasionally. If you will leave it - than use danishs solution (`: this()`), if not then:

```
public Test(string Mode)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   RunFirst_Settings();
   UserLogin login = new UserLogin();
   login.Hide();
   login.Visible = false;

   parentform = Mode;
}
```

Comment: thanks.Suppose if i want to use my default constructor in any other form then ? whether it works r not?

Comment: Well, if you want you default constructor - then leave it and use :)